# How does Flink sink behave when recovering from a savepoint?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-streaming, sink

Curious to know how [elasticsearch sink connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/elasticsearch/) behaves when a recovery from a savepoint on Flink is completed.

Would it delete/update the documents on ES sink destination by reverting the commits up to the point of savepoint time or should some other mechanism recover ES index for them to sync up again?

I can generalize this question to other sink connectors as well, such as Kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink can support exactly once delivery through two-phase commit, and end-to-end exactly once delivery also need connector guarantee

Kafka Source and Sink support exactly once delivery，but es connector only support at lease once delivery，after es sink is restored from savepoint, there will be no reverting operation

Comment: Thank you. I guess that’s fine if es sink operations are idempotent and you can replay the events and continue sinking. However, more curious to know how to rectify a stateful streaming application when you notice that some corrupt data from upstream is consumed and the sunk data is eventually corrupted as well. There should be an easier way to revert this without replaying the entire upstream events from the beginning up to the offset of the first corrupted event.

Comment: Here is my opinion on this issue, es sink do not support exactly once delivery, and do not have replay mechanism to rectify the sunk data, it provide at least once delivery via upsert